# Performance user timings API measure not working properly when started from 'navigationStart'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

To measure the performance of an app using the performance user timigs API, I use the following code in the place where the application is loaded completely.

```
window.performance.mark('stop-step');
window.performance.measure('app_load_performance', 'navigationStart', 'stop-step');
```

While profiling, in the performance tab, the Timings section show the performance marker only when web app was refreshed in a browser window where the web app is already running.

If this is profiled from a new browser tab where the web app is newly executed, the profiling does not show the performance marker.

This is a react app. Could there be something that is limiting the application to show the performance marker from the new tab?

Comment: I know this may be obvious (but sometimes it just takes a second pair of eyes) but are you sure that the above is actually called? Have you fallen back to gold old `console.log` to check that something isn't causing it to not be called in the first place, such as a different execution pattern on a fresh run vs one with a warm cache? I assume you have no console errors that could be the cause of this (yet again obvious I know but sometimes easy to miss when you are "in the middle" of the fight!)

Answer (score 0):

According to [Mozilla Navigation and resource timings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/Navigation_and_resource_timings);

> The **performanceTiming API**, a JavaScript API for measuring the
> loading performance of the requested page, **is deprecated** but
> supported in all browsers. It has been **replaced with** the
> **performanceNavigationTiming API**.

What happens when there is no context and the mark navigationStart is pointed in the same page:

> When the prompt for unload terminates on the previous document in the
> same browsing context. **If there is no previous document**, this value
> will be the same as **PerformanceTiming.fetchStart**.

And in the [new API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigation_timing_API):

> The Navigation Timing API provides data that can be used to measure
> the performance of a web site. **Unlike JavaScript-based libraries** that
> have historically been used to collect similar information, the
> Navigation Timing API can be much more accurate and reliable.

Also if you scroll down in the [new API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigation_timing_API) page, you can see that the fetchStart mark has been marked for deprecation.

There is a high chance that for some reason your browser is no longer handling this mark. And the new library has no backward compatibility with the old one. So this would explain why you can see the performance when there is a previous document, but you can't see it when there isn't.